# Why do I need to restart App Engine Server when modifying a JSP?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine

I have set up an Eclipse environment in order to run my App Engine application following the Google guidelines.
Everything works fine, but I don't understand why if I edit a JSP while the server is up I need to restart it to see the modifications. Is there any configuration change that I need to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Since JSPs are compiled to Servlets, you need to recompile edited JSPs and deploy them in your running container. You'll find plenty of information on this topic on stackoverflow since this is not specific to app engine. Just search for something like "jsp changes".

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue is that eclipse does it automatically but the changes are not deployed after having edited a JSP on the fly, I am trying to find out how to configure it

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: double click on the GAE server, select "Automatically publish when resources change" and lower the publishing interval.